# Redirect login user or admin to specific page or view depending upon role in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

There are several module in my Asp.net project and several user role also.
I want to do is, if user login to the system, it redirected to User dashboard and admin to admin dashboard. i have used Asp.net Identity for Login and register.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check role in sign in action.Set different returnUrls for different roles.Here is sample code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    var returnUrl = "defaultUrl";
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "role1"))
                        {
                            returnUrl = "url1";
                        }
                        if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "role2"))
                        {
                            returnUrl = "url2";
                        }
                    }
                    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                        
                    }
                   
         }
         return View();
```